# Use of table in stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I have following stored procedure. I want `case when` to show the result for some values defined in some table. The number of rows in that table are not certain. How can I use `case when` within a `while` loop to give me the result for different conditions. Those conditions are defined in a table. I tried the following but got an error:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS CNT, AGE_RANGE
FROM
(
  SELECT
   ID,
  (
    (DECLARE pTemp ref_cursor for
    Select * form age_range;

    OPEN pTemp
      FETCH NEXT FROM pTemp into getRange
        While (FETCH_STATUS = 0)
      select rang
      FETCH NEXT FROM pTemp into getRange )
      fn_get_split_values(getRange , min, max)
     case 


      WHEN payer_age >= min AND payer_age <=max THEN 'mini-maxi'
      ELSE 'NO CATEGORY'
      END AS AGE_RANGE

   )
  from REMIT_WORK_QUEUE
  )
```

Comment: fn_get_split_values(getRange , min, max) is a method to return min and max values for a range say min-max

Comment: it's a store**D** procedure - as in **STORED** inside your database (it has nothing to do with a *store*)

Comment: actually i am new to stack overflow. i found people here very responsive.. i dont know where is the link to accept answer... can some once help...

Comment: "i dont know where is the link to accept answer... can some once help" - Try the FAQ link at the top of the page...

Comment: thanx for guideline frnds... see i made it 100 percent.. from future i'll keep in mind to accept best answer for my question... thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you're using a `count()` in the `SELECT` statement, but you are not designating a `GROUP BY` to allow the count to consolidate the `age_range` column together if that makes sense. Try adding this line to the end:

`GROUP BY AGE_RANGE`